# Error to deploy dist to github-pages, return wrong resources url and an Empty pages

Tags: webpack, github-pages

First, I build a js project to directory `dist`, and success to `npm run dist` on localhost. Then, I try to deploy to `github-pages`, but it return an **Empty page**, with the **wrong resource URL**.

#### How can I config or fix this problems?

All files can see in my github project: https://github.com/DiroKate/SysuhikerCC/tree/gh-pages

Here is my details:

1. Deploy my `dist` to branch `gh-pages`:`git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`
2. Access the project github-pages URL: `dirokate.github.io/SysuhikerCC/` , it return Empty. I think the correct resource URL is `dirokate.github.io/SysuhikerCC/{resource}`. But the URL it showed is `dirokate.github.io/{resource}`, no **project** name.

Comment: How did you go with this? Are you able to answer your own question now? If you could leave an answer for those that follow in your footsteps it'd be greatly appreciated. Thx